# bsearch and struct (custom type)

Tags: c, pointers, bsearch

I have an array like this:

```
typedef struct INSTR
{
    char* str;
    int  argc;
} INSTR;
const static INSTR instructions[] = { {"blue",1}, {"green",2} };
```

then I tried to do a `bsearch`, but I'm getting `Segmentation fault` message:

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const INSTR *aa = (INSTR*)a;
    const INSTR *bb = (INSTR*)b; 
    // if I "return 0;" here i get no error.
    return strcmp(aa->str, bb->str);
}
```

.

```
char *str = get_string(src_buff, size);
bsearch(str, instructions,
        sizeof(instructions) / sizeof(instructions[0]),
        sizeof(instructions[0]), comp);
```

Comment: What is value of `str` argument to `bsearch`? Can you post compilable example that produces the seg fault?

Comment: I updated, sorry. But now i think i can see my mistake hehehe. I forgot to pass a structure, i'm passing a string instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `comp()` function is incorrect.From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/bsearch/):

> comparator
>       Function that compares two elements. The function shall follow this prototype:

```
int comparator ( const void * pkey, const void * pelem );
```

> ```
> The function must accept two parameters: the first one pointing to the
> key object, and the second one to an element of the array, both
> type-casted as void*. The function should cast the parameters back to
> some data type and compare them.
> ```

The first argument to your `comp()` is a `const char*`, not a `INSTR*`.

Change to:

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const INSTR *bb = (INSTR*)b; 
    return strcmp((const char*)a, bb->str);
}
```

Or, change the `key` to be a `INSTR*` instead of `const char*`.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a variable named `str` as your key, but in the comparison function you're treating it like an `INSTR`. If your key is a string, then `a` should actually be a pointer to it, and you should be using

```
return strcmp(a, bb->str);
```

That's based on the assumption that `str` is in fact a string, but we can't bu sure without seeing it declared (I'm guessing it is unless you've got some rather unusual naming conventions).

EDIT:

Based on update it *is* a string.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to your `comp` function will be the argument that you passed as the first argument to `bsearch`, not a `INSTR`. Your comparison function should act accordingly:

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char* str = (const char*)a;
    const INSTR *bb = (INSTR*)b; 
    // if I "return 0;" here i get no error.
    return strcmp(str, bb->str);
}
```